# Flagging a moderator's comment or answer

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

If somebody is to flag a moderator's answers or comment as rude or offensive, would that moderator be able to see you have flagged them, and then just decline it? Or is it up to another moderator to sort it out so it is fair?

I do not wish to do this but I was just wondering.

Comment: Did you find any?  Being 1+ yr member I haven't seen any.

Comment: @Praveen: I have seen it a few times, and it was always handled to my satisfaction.

Comment: Yes, I happened to see self or very suspicious decline at least for this, unfortunately, not even once, feeling no shame, but luckily then the 20K+ people got the answer deleted voted.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Mods can see and handle all flags, including the ones cast against their own posts and comments.  But generally speaking, mods defer to other mods to handle flags against their own posts.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to hear :)

Comment: Unless, that is, you agree with the flag. Then feel free to process it.

Comment: Could you just imagine if said post would result in a 24 temporary ban in normal circumstances? 'You know what I agree, I was an ass... I'll just ban myself now!'

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Kind of unrelated, but has a mod ever banned another mod? lol

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not to my knowledge.  We just discuss it and work it out.  By the time you become a mod, hopefully you're beyond all of the pettiness and it boils down to a simple disagreement over policies.

Answer (score 13):

> would that moderator be able to see you have flagged them, and then just decline it?

Well, yes they would be able to see that. And yes, they would be able to decline it.

**However**:

> Or is it up to another moderator to sort it out so it is fair?

That's the modus operandi - most moderators, if anything they posted (question, answer, comment) gets flagged, will step away and let another, impartial mod deal with it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anyway to validate whether a flag has actually has been handled by another mod?

Comment: Thanks @Oded . Good to hear there is a modus operandi in place.

Comment: Where mods are involved, we always try to have a modus in place. Operandi or otherwise.

Comment: @sam another mod can retrospectively check who handled it.

Comment: @Flexo That's **"Who watches the Watchmen?"** territory.  Hopefully the buck stops with [galactically-agreed-upon robots obeying uniform mathematical protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still).  (Or barring that, a fair dice roll.)

Comment: Actually, why isn't this hard-coded into the system? Any reason to have mods be able to see flags against them?

Comment: I presume that's related to a matter of time to developer verses the trust given to moderators. It could be made to work that way, but moderators are trusted with the operation of the site, if they can't step away and allow an impartial mod deal with the complaint, they probably shouldn't be a mod

Comment: That's not a bad point by @Mehrdad ...  the final answer is to vote them out next time if there ever were a problem, but it's not the worst idea to also block the flagged person from handling it directly.

Comment: @CyanAngel: Except the problem is the user who is having a problem with the mod's comments might not actually trust the mod.

Comment: @Oded, How do we request a second opinion on a flag reversal, if we called out a mod (10k rep) for being overly harsh and immediately after that we got serial downvoted (and flagged those), if those flags were reversed?

Comment: @toddmo - you can always contact the Community Team (Stack Exchange employees) and explain. Use the [contact form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) (also linked in the footer of every site).